# No module named 'airflow' when initializing Apache airflow docker

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I am trying to run apache airflow as a docker on a Centos 7 machine.
I followed all the instructions here:https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html
when i am trying to initialize the docker by running docker-compose up airflow-init

i am getting this error

```
[root@centos7 centos]# docker-compose up airflow-init
Creating network "centos_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "centos_postgres-db-volume" with default driver
Creating centos_redis_1    ... done
Creating centos_postgres_1 ... done
Creating centos_airflow-init_1 ... done
Attaching to centos_airflow-init_1
airflow-init_1       | BACKEND=postgresql+psycopg2
airflow-init_1       | DB_HOST=postgres
airflow-init_1       | DB_PORT=5432
airflow-init_1       |
airflow-init_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow.__main__ import main
airflow-init_1       | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'
airflow-init_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow.__main__ import main
airflow-init_1       | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'
airflow-init_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow.__main__ import main
airflow-init_1       | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'
airflow-init_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow.__main__ import main
airflow-init_1       | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'
airflow-init_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow.__main__ import main
airflow-init_1       | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'
centos_airflow-init_1 exited with code 1
```

i used the standard YAML file from here:https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/docker-compose.yaml
i found that it's a known issue here:https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14520
but i could not understand how to solve this problem.
any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem this way.

login with a non-root user.

find your user id :

```
echo $UID
```

create **.env** file and put these lines inside it  . replace 4003 with your user id:

```
AIRFLOW_UID=4003
AIRFLOW_GID=0
```

If you have not created these directories, first create these and run docker-compose:

```
sudo mkdir ./dags ./logs ./plugins
sudo chmod 777 -R logs 
sudo docker-compose up airflow-init
sudo docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
There is a bug on version 2.0.1 that doesn’t let you run the airflow containers using root.
You have to run the installation under another user name (with sudo).

Comment: Can you expand on this? I'm seeing the bug and not running as root.

Answer (score 1):

Running Airflow in `docker-compose` on Linux (Mint 20.2 Uma 64-bit) already required me to set up `AIRFLOW_UID` and `AIRFLOW_GID` and I still got the aforementioned `ModuleNotFound` issue, which points that `airflow` in not in the `PYTHONPATH`. This might be due to the fact that you are not logging in as the `airflow` user (`UID=50000`). So setting the `PYTHONPATH` resolved my issue. Here how, hope that it is useful for someone:

- I spawned only one container manually as my user ID (e.g. with a `sleep infinity` command) and connected to it using `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> /bin/bash` in order to investigate further:

  - running both `airflow` and `import airflow` (from python) both had this issue which confirmed my assumption
  - check where `airflow` is located and see if it is the `PYTHONPATH`

    ```bash
    $ which airflow
    /home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow

    $ echo $PYTHONPATH
    /opt/airflow:
    ```
  - since however, `/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow` is simply a python script that imports `airflow` from `/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` add this path to `PYTHONPATH` and run `airflow` to test

    ```bash
    $ PYTHONPATH="/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
    $ airflow
    # output omitted
    ```
- At the end I added this to my `docker-compose.yaml` file and ran `docker-compose up` to run `airflow`.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if `AIRFLOW_GID` is not set properly in the `.env` file.

The instructions include running the command `echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env`.
To check this worked as expected, look at the contents of the `.env` file by running `cat .env`.
You should see something that looks like this:

```
AIRFLOW_UID=1000
AIRFLOW_GID=0
```

If you do not you might need to manually edit the `.env` file to set the airflow uid and gid.